# Bank Statements to Produce for Canada Visa

Tags: visas, canada, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

I am going for a conference to Canada. The trip is being sponsored by my company here in Nigeria. I have an issues with presentation of Bank Statements.

Which bank Statement am I to provide? The one for the company which also has a letter confirming that I am going to Canada for them, or just my bank statement?

Answer (score 1):

Both. You produce the company statements because they’re the sponsor. However if it a huge internationally known organization like Microsoft or Shell or Google, a bank statement from the company is not required. The letter of sponsorship is enough.

You produce your statements to show your financial position in Nigeria which will demonstrate you’re comfortable enough in Nigeria not to overstay/abscond.

See: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab?rq=1) which is applicable although written for UK applicants.